# Want pushed navigationController from a subview to appear on full screen, not subview

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, subview, navigationbar

I have `UINavigationController` where I have a `UITableViewController` as **subview** with another `navigationController`. **But the problem is that, the pushed navigationController from that subview is appearing in the subview only.**
 I want the pushed `navigationcontroller` from the subview to appear in entire screen, not as subview.

How can i achieve it? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: When you are talking about UINavigationController, are you talking about UINavigationBar?

Comment: Yes, precisely. I want the top navigarBar to be hidden from the first navigationcontroller.

Comment: [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

Comment: This hides the bar from the mainView too. I want bar to be hidden only when a view is pushed.

Comment: Write it on the viewDidLoad of the pushed Controller.

Comment: That will hide the subview navigationbar. Not the top most. How can i call the first navigation bar?

Comment: Have you tried it? In my view, it should hide the parent navigation bar.

Comment: the subview is also a UINavigationController. So it will hide the navigationBar from subview only.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, it will help if you at least correct the classes names. Probably, the only thing you need is to get the correct reference, and to do it you need to understand what `navigationController` property returns. It returns only the navigation controller which has the receiver view controller at the stack, not the navigation controller with a view controller at it's stack that has a view with the receiver's view controller view as a subview.

Comment: can i hide it using the reference or storyboard id when a specific viewController is displayed?

Comment: Image added in the original post.

Comment: Does your user journey allow you to present the Job screen as a modal view controller instead?  You could provide a UINavigationBar in the Xib.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show some of your code? You need to push your new ViewController onto the outer UINavigationController.